# Updating custom page layout in a Managed Package

Tags: managed-package, page-layout

I have a Managed Package, including a custom Lead page layout, which was released a while ago. I made a change to the layout and uploaded a new package version (Beta 1). I see in the package description as well when I install the package that the new layout is not being taken into the new version.
Anyone knows why and what I need to do for this to work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per the [SFDC ISV packaging guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_packageable_components.htm) you cannot update the page layouts .The page layouts are not up-gradable and hence only way you can launch new layout is create another page layout and probably deprecate the older one .

Comment: Pity more flexibility in this area has never attracted much interest https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BpMpAAK.